# Codeigniter 2 $this->ip_address() not returning ip address

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well, I'm trying to log user login history, so for this I need to track user's ip address.
I used:

```
$this->input->ip_address();
```

This should return the `ip address` of the machine, if user has valid ip, or should return `0.0.0.0` if the user doesn't have a valid IP. But in my case it's returning neither.

It is returning just an unusual format.

```
::1
```

P.S. I'm checking it in my local computer.

**EDIT :**

Thanks all who commented. But still it is strange things going out here. I have two separate applications running in my same machine. Both applications are made in Codeigniter 2. The first one records `0.0.0.0` and the second one records `::1`. Isnt both application should have returned same thing?

Thanks

Comment: This a valid IPv6 Adress. ::1 means localhost which is equivalent to IPv4 127.0.0.1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: BTW: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182457/

Comment: @gearsdigital, Thanks buddy, please check Edit to my question

Comment: "Returns the IP address for the current user. If the IP address is not valid, the function will return an IP of: 0.0.0.0". You might wanna check it with $this->input->valid_ip($ip)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::1` **is** a valid IP address.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: Are you running the exact same version of CodeIgniter? On the same server? Testing from the same interface?

Comment: well application is different, but the codeigniter core modules are of same version. And i m running it in same machine

Comment: @Sabin There must be something related to the application, since it's 2 different applications. Nothing I can help you with I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking if ::1 is present in your hosts file, and comment it out just to see if both of your applications then behave the same.

This thread has some useful info:  http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/205222

In particular

> So your machine is running dual stack (which most modern OS’ses do these days), and when they do, they prefer IPv6 over IPv4.
>
> Either remove IPv6 from your localhost interface, remove IPv6 support from your local webserver (have it only listen to your v4 address), [snipped]